# how to make the buttons fit to all screens?

Tags: android, android-studio, button

I have used buttons as squares shapes(165dpx165dp), but when i change the screen size the button keep the same dimension which make it invisible or too large in some screens.

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fneclis_l1s1_bg"
    tools:context=".AllButtonsFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="404dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Phy1"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/bl"
                android:text="@string/physique_1"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Infor1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Math1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Math1"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/rd"
                android:text="@string/math_matiques_1"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Chemie1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Phy1"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Chemie1"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/or"
                android:text="@string/structure_de_la_mati_re"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/MR"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Infor1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Math1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Infor1"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/gr"
                android:text="@string/informatique_1"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/MST1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Chemie1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Phy1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/MST1"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/rd"
                android:text="@string/les_m_tiers_en_sciences_et_technologies_1"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Fr"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/MR"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Infor1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/MR"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/bl"
                android:text="@string/m_thodologie_de_la_r_daction"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/An"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/MST1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Chemie1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/An"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#07254e"
                android:text="@string/anglais"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Fr"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MR" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Fr"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/jn"
                android:text="@string/fran_ais"
                android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/An"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MST1" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> i want to make my button more Interact with screens sizes if that
>   possible

this is just to avoid the stupid notice of 'it looks like your question is only a code'
I have used buttons as squares shapes(165dpx165dp), but when i change the screen size the button keep the same dimension which make it invisible or too large in some screens.

Comment: share your layout file

Comment: *the button keep the same dimension*!! You set them to keep the same dimension

Comment: You set the dimension to be 165dp so this is what you get

Comment: so what mus i do ? please

Comment: @HonEyMonEy did you try it?

Comment: yes but it make button lose there square shape

Answer (score 2):

If you want the buttons to change the dimension side by side and fit all screen sizes and orientation, then you can accomplish it with weights on a Linear layout.

Comment: please check my layout and change it to be flexible !!